# Giving arbitrary weight to training data improves my Nu-SVR predictor. What should I do?

Tags: regression, svm, standardization, data-preprocessing

I preprocessed my data by calculating z-scores of each feature, and trained a Nu-SVR model for a regression.

While preprocessing, I expanded some features' scale up to 10~30 fold by mistake,
and soon realized that this mis-preprocessed training data outperforms properly preprocess training data.

I could get best result by mimicking such 'mistake'. Giving some arbitrary weights (multiplying 10 after z-score normalization) to specific features showed outstanding result.

However, I cannot find any 'theoretical' reason to do that.
Is it okay to apply such weight? Is there any theoretically right way to calculate such weight for SVR?

Following is an answer to RickyFox's comment:

Features that I multiplied are uniformly distributed, while other features are close to skewed gaussian and show the very long tail. Actually, these long tails make min-max range different among features after z-score normalization. Thus I also tried min-max scaling, but it did not improve prediction at all.

Comment: What was the nature of your error in the preprocessing? You wrote that *some* features were scaled up, can you elaborate what these features were?

Comment: I added answers to your comment in the main text above. Thanks.